# IIS7 - Client side caching a .ashx file that already has no-cache data set

Tags: caching, iis-7, client-side

In IIS7, I have a .ashx file from a third party which sets caching headers to be `no-cache,private`

I want this to be cached on the client so I have added the following code to the global.asax

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Path.IndexOf("Script.ashx") > -1)
    {
      Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
      Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
      Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
      Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Language"] = true;
    }
}
```

I would expect the resulting cache information to be `public, Expires: Thu, 29 Sep 2011 16:06:27 GMT`

Instead however I get the Franken-response of `no-cache,public  Expires: Thu, 29 Sep 2011 16:06:27 GMT`

So the code is taking replacing the private with public as I want but it fails to replace the no-cache directive.  Is it possible to replace the no-cache directive with this approach: if so what am I missing; if not what other approaches are there?

Comment: One obvious alternative is to modify the response headers directly instead of using the `Cache.*` APIs. But I'm sure there's a better way. How does the ashx set *its* cache-related headers?

Comment: The .ashx passes off to a closed .dll which I have no control over.

Comment: [Technically, you don't need actual control. :)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/files/ILSpy/1.0/ILSpy_1.0.0.1000_Binaries.zip/download) I'm thinking the ashx does frankenstyle header modifications that confuse the `Cache.*` API, which could [leave you no choice but to modify the response headers directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx). If you remove the `cache-control` header altogether before using the `Cache.*` API perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code fails in IIS7 Classic mode but the Integrated mode the code works as expected and produces sensible response headers.  I assume this is due to the way that classic works similar to an ISAPI filter.  I have switched to Integrated mode and this has solved the issue.